# why is the accuracy of my RNN model going up and down so much

Tags: tensorflow, keras

So I am using RNNs and using the train and test datasets. I have pre processed all the data and used one hot encoding, normalization, feature selection etc but the accuracy of the model is looking a bit off on the testing set and I am not sure what it means. It could be overfitting possibly? I have plotted the outcome on a line graph for the outcome of the model accuracy and the loss of the model if it helps.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units= 20, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape =(1,121)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(LSTM(units= 40,  activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(LSTM(units= 60,  activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.add(LSTM(units= 80, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(LSTM(units= 100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
          
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

 
history = model.fit(x_train_binary, y_train2, batch_size=128, epochs=125,  validation_data=(x_test_binary, y_test2))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi rcon313, welcome to Cross Validated. Good question. It looks to me like overfitting indeed but I don't have much of experience with RNN. What if you reduce the layers or the amount of units?

Comment: hey, I removed all the LSTM layers apart from one and it seemed to work a lot better, possibly because its in binary classification so its a lot more simpler